# Array reference/value

Tags: arrays, swift

I have some arrays:

```
var arrayOne = [String]()
var arrayTwo = [String]()
var arrayThree = [String]()
```

Then I write a function. I give a number, it returns my one of these arrays:

```
func get_array(aNumber:Int) -> NSArray {
   var arr = self.arrayOne //default
   if aNumber == 1 {
        arr = self.arrayOne
   } else if aNumber == 2 {
       arr = self.arrayTwo
   } else if aNumber == 3 {
       arr = self.arrayThree
   }
   return arr!
}
```

Then for instance I do:

```
var myArray = get_array(2)
myArray.append("hello")
NSLog("myArray: %@", myArray) // Ok, myArray was modified!!

NSLog("arrayTwo: %@", arrayTwo) // **Shit, arrayTwo was not modified!!** I was expecting myArray to be pointing to arrayTwo, so they are the same object
```

How can do this???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305989/swift-array-pass-by-value-same-memory-address

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27539533/3804019 similar question

Answer (score 0):

Swift arrays are value types. It means that

```
let array2 = array1
```

makes a *copy* of array1. So when you access array2 it is not the same array anymore as array1, it is another object with the same content.

This is different from NSArray and NSMutableArray which are a reference type: when you do

```
let nsarray2 = nsarray1
```

this time nsarray2 is a reference to nsarray1 and they are actually the same object.

Comment: I understand. But why in the world they changed the behavior?? NSDictionary and NSArray worked like a charm. Are they going to be available for long? Or are they deprecated and I should move to Array and Dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

In Swift `Arrays` are value types so they get copied if you assign, return or pass as parameter.

To make this work as expected you have to make a wrapper (class):

```
class ArrayWrapper<T> {
    var array: [T]
    init(_ array: [T] = []) {
        self.array = array
    }
}

var arrayOne = ArrayWrapper<String>()
var arrayTwo = ArrayWrapper<String>()
var arrayThree = ArrayWrapper<String>()

func get_array(aNumber:Int) -> ArrayWrapper<String> {
   var arr = self.arrayOne //default
   if aNumber == 1 {
        arr = self.arrayOne
   } else if aNumber == 2 {
       arr = self.arrayTwo
   } else if aNumber == 3 {
       arr = self.arrayThree
   }
   return arr
}

// in case of your function I would suggest to use switch instead:
func getArray(aNumber:Int) -> ArrayWrapper<String> {
   switch aNumber {
   case 1: return self.arrayOne
   case 2: return self.arrayTwo
   case 3: return self.arrayThree
   default: return self.arrayOne
   }
}

// so you modify the Array as following:
var myArray = get_array(2)
myArray.array.append("hello")
```